# Eliminate repetitive tag in Data Grid Columns C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have Data Grid that has 60 columns in WPF project,

I have to add the following tag per every column which makes the XAML file huge
Are there any way to generalize this tags?

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
                <Setter.Value>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ToolTipConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="RowID" />
                      <Binding Path="BusinessPhone" />
                 </MultiBinding>
              </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
       </Style>
     </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: please reformat your question - it's too intrusive

Comment: How to make a parametrised Style ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply that style to all columns in the datagrid, put a style for DataGridCell in the DataGrid's resources. If you want to only apply it to certain columns, then name the style and apply the style by name to each column. Example

To apply to all columns:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
            <Setter.Value>
             <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ToolTipConverter}">
                  <Binding Path="RowID" />
                  <Binding Path="BusinessPhone" />
             </MultiBinding>
          </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

To apply to individual columns:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="YourStyleName">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
            <Setter.Value>
             <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ToolTipConverter}">
                  <Binding Path="RowID" />
                  <Binding Path="BusinessPhone" />
             </MultiBinding>
          </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </Style>
```

....

```
<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource YourStyleName} " >
```

Comment: The problem is the binding itself in the style should be variable not static to specific columns in this case , the style is fixed to RowID and BussinessPhone, I need them to be a variable